# Historial de mensajes con PHP, MYSQL y AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Estoy creando una especie de Imbox, un chat por así decirlo pero con la diferencia es que yo no quiero que sea un chat general, donde todos los usuarios escriban y les aparezca a todos, así que hice el sistema reservado entre dos usuarios similar a facebook, funciona cuando están chateando a tiempo real, aparece uno debajo del otro, y los meto en una tabla, y los coloco en unos campos de la tabla para que el sistema sepa que son ellos dos los que hablan y no otros usuarios, esto funciona correctamente, cada quien tiene su propio chat y ningún otro usuario puede ver lo que están chateando, lo que busco principalmente, el problema esta en el Historial, cuando recargo la pagina, aparece el historial pero se ordenan por listas, Por ejemplo:

Pedro chatea con Juan: en tiempo real, Escribe Pedro y Juan y se ve la conversacion una debajo de la otra, como Facebook, pero cuando recargo la pagina, donde debería mostrar el historial de lo que hablaron, Aparecen todos los mensajes de Juan y todos los mensajes de Pedro, pero todos juntos, es decir si pedro mando 50 mensajes, salen primero sus 50 mensajes y luego los de Juan, cuando yo quiero mostrar uno debajo de otra

```
introducir el código aquí

      //CHAT USER 1
public function dataChat($data_from, $data_to, $from_name, $to_name, $name_session, $foto){      
    try{
    $stm = "SELECT
            *
            FROM
            chat
            WHERE
            id_from = :id_self
            AND
            from_name = :from
            AND
            to_name = :to_name
            AND
            id_to = :id_to                           
            ";
     $data = $this->BBDD->prepare($stm);
     $data->execute(array(
         ":id_self"=>  htmlspecialchars(addslashes($data_from)),
         ":from"=>  htmlspecialchars(addslashes($from_name)),
         ":to_name"=>  htmlspecialchars(addslashes($to_name)),
         ":id_to"=>  htmlspecialchars(addslashes($data_to))
     ));
     $count = $data->rowCount();
     $performance = $data->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    foreach($performance as $value){
        if($count!=0){
            $_SESSION["chat_data"] = $this->chat_with($data_to);
            if($name_session === $value->from_name && $_SESSION["chat_data"] && $value->to_name === $to_name){
            echo '<div class="row">';
                     echo   '<div class="col-lg-12">';
                     echo       '<div class="media">';
                     echo           '<a class="pull-left" href="#">';
                     echo               '<img class="media-object img-circle" width="50px" src='."avatar/$foto".' alt="">';
                                echo '</a>';
                                echo '<div class="media-body">';
                                echo    '<h4 class="media-heading">'.$value->from_name;
                                echo       ' <span class="small pull-right">'.$value->time.'</span>';
                                echo    '</h4>';
                                echo    $value->message;
                                echo  '</div>';
                                echo '</div>';
                        echo '</div>';
                    echo '</div>';
                    echo '<hr>';

            }else{
                header("location:dashboard.php");
            }

        }

    }

     //print_r($performance);        
    }catch(PDOException $ex){
        die("Error al leer este chat" . $ex->getLine() . PHP_EOL . $ex->getCode() . " " . PHP_EOL. $ex->getMessage());
    }finally{
       // $this->BBDD = NULL;
    } 

}
//VERIFICAR CONVERSACION
private function chat_with($id_to){        
    try{
          $stm = "SELECT
                  *
                  FROM
                  imbox
                  WHERE
                  id = :name
                  ";
          $data_session = $this->BBDD->prepare($stm);
          $data_session->execute(array(":name"=>  htmlspecialchars(addslashes($id_to))));
          $count = $data_session->rowCount();
          if($count!=0){
              return TRUE;
          }else{
              return FALSE;
          }
          $this->BBDD = NULL;
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        die("Error al leer este chat" . $ex->getLine() . PHP_EOL . $ex->getCode() . " " . PHP_EOL. $ex->getMessage());
    }                         
}
//CHAT USER2 // Recibe la respuesta del CHAT 1
public function imbox($from_name, $id_data, $to_name){
    try{
        $stm = "SELECT
                *
                FROM
                imbox
                WHERE
                nick_usuario = :nick
                AND
                id = :id_usuario
                AND
                de_name = :to
                ";
        $data = $this->BBDD->prepare($stm);
        $data->execute(array(
            ":nick"=>  htmlspecialchars(addslashes($to_name)),
            ":id_usuario"=>  htmlspecialchars(addslashes($id_data)),
            ":to"=>  htmlspecialchars(addslashes($from_name))
        ));

        $data_table = $data->rowCount();
        //print_r($data_table);
        if($data_table!=0){
            $avatar = "SELECT
                       foto
                       FROM
                       datos_profesionales
                       WHERE
                       nick_usuario = ?
                       ";
         $data_from = $this->BBDD->prepare($avatar);
         $data_from->execute(array(htmlspecialchars(addslashes($from_name))));
         //$fotoLog = $data_from->rowCount();
         //print_r($fotoLog);
         $fotoLog = $data_from->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
         foreach($fotoLog as $foto){                                
         } 
         $data_chat = $data->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
         foreach($data_chat as $data_key){ 
             echo '<div id="chatLastData">';
             echo '<div class="row">';
                     echo   '<div class="col-lg-12">';
                     echo       '<div class="media">';
                     echo           '<a class="pull-left" href="#">';
                     echo               '<img class="media-object img-circle" width="50px" src='."avatar/$foto->foto".' alt="">';
                                echo '</a>';
                                echo '<div class="media-body">';
                                echo    '<h4 class="media-heading">'.$data_key->de_name;
                                echo       ' <span class="small pull-right">'.$data_key->hora.'</span>';
                                echo    '</h4>';
                                echo    $data_key->mailbox;
                                echo  '</div>';
                                echo '</div>';
                        echo '</div>';
                    echo '</div>';
                    echo '</div>';
                    echo '<hr>';
         }
         $this->BDDD = NULL;
        }
        //$this->BBDD = NULL;
    } catch (PDOException $ex) {

        die("Error al leer este chat" . $ex->getLine() . PHP_EOL . $ex->getCode() . " " . PHP_EOL. $ex->getMessage());
```

```html
<div class="portlet-footer">
                        <form id="chat_message" role="form" action="wp-admin/message.php" method="POST" accept-charset="">
                            <input type="hidden" name="id_from" value="<?php echo $_GET["id_from"] ?>">
                            <input type="hidden" name="name_from" value="<?php echo $_GET["from"] ?>">
                            <input type="hidden" name="id_to" value="<?php echo $data->id ?>">
                            <input type="hidden" name="name_to" value="<?php echo $_GET["to"] ?>">
                            <input type="hidden" name="time" value="<?php echo $date?>">
                            <input type="hidden" name="photo" value="<?php echo $photo->foto ?>">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="chat_data" value="" placeholder="Enter message..."></input>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Send</button>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        <script>
                        jQuery("#chat_message").submit(
                                function(event){                                    
                                    jQuery.ajax({                                     
                                      url: "wp-admin/message.php",
                                      type: "POST",
                                      cache: false,                                     
                                      data: jQuery("#chat_message").serialize(),
                                      success: function(ajaxResponse){
                                          jQuery("#chats").append(ajaxResponse).scrollTop(jQuery("#chats").prop("scrollHeight"));
                                          jQuery("#chat_message")[0].reset();
                                      },
                                      error: function(ajaxResponse){
                                          console.log(ajaxResponse);
                                      }
                                    });
                                   return false;                               
                                });                                                             
                        </script>                     
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta ordenar los mensajes por su fecha y hora de creación, tu tabla debe tener una columna con la fecha y hora de creación de cada mensaje:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM imbox 
 WHERE nick_usuario = :nick
   AND id = :id_usuario
   AND de_name = :to
 ORDER BY mi_columna   --Para ordenarlos
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sorting-rows.html

Answer (score 0):

Muchachos, la forma de resolverlo fue catastrofica pero logre hacerlo, en parte el error estaba en porque para mantener la seguridad de que solo dos personas puedan ver lo que chatean, la información que se metia en mi tabla de chat, la volcaba en otra a su vez que se llamaba imbox, obviamente al recuperar los datos me iba a devolver ambas tablas, la forma de resolverlo fue migrar las dos tablas en una, y con unas sentencias evaluar si estan chateando esos dos usuarios o no, la forma de solucionarlo fue esta:

```
 $stm ="SELECT *,
        (
             CASE 
     WHEN id_from = :data_from && id_to = :data_to THEN 'true'
     WHEN from_name = :from && to_name = :to_name THEN 'true'        
     WHEN id_from = :data_from2 && id_to = :data_to2 THEN 'true'
     WHEN from_name = :from2 && to_name = :to_name2 THEN 'true'       
    ELSE 'FALSE'
    END) AS conversation 
    FROM chat  
    ORDER BY hora";
```

Con el True y el false que devuelve, ya puedo manipular la seguridad del sistema